# SWIFT 2.2 : Using a method of a new swift uiview class from a different uiview class

Tags: swift

I have the following 2 different UIView classes

```
class mainview:UIView{

some code here   
}
```

and second one

```
class animateview:UIView{

func animate(limit:float_t)
{
     animation code written here
}
}
```

I want to access my function "**animateview**" with a button click from my mainview. Something like calling the function in **animateview** class with a value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you think about adding an outlet or init that view in that second view? are the separated with a wall or something?

Comment: you can create oultet of animateview in mainView  class and   what are you doing in animate function? you can also create extentsion of UIView and declare function and use it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

one way is to extend the UIView.

```
extension UIView {
    func animate(limit:float_t) {
        //animation code written here
    }
}


class mainview:UIView{

    func buttonClick() {
        self.animate(4.0)
    }
}
```

Note: when you use extension an any class, that function is available to all class of that type.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) , but in that case, the whole view is changing or animating, I need to animate only one particular custom view that's animate view inside the main view